# How do I fold an MPL type list into a variadic container?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl, template-templates

If I have a list of types, how can I get a type with that list as it's variadic parameters?

In other words, I want to go from this:

```cpp
boost::mpl::list<foo, bar, baz, quux>
```

To:

```cpp
types<foo, bar, baz, quux>
```

(Order not important)

Here's my attempt using `fold`:

```cpp
typedef boost::mpl::list<foo, bar, baz, quux> type_list;

template <typename... Ts>
struct types {};

template <template <typename... Ts> class List, typename T>
struct add_to_types {
  typedef types<T, typename Ts...> type;
};

typedef boost::mpl::fold<
  type_list,
  types<>,
  add_to_types<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2>
>::type final_type;
```

Unfortunately this gives me errors regarding the placeholders:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class ... Ts> class List, class T> struct add_to_types'
error:   expected a class template, got 'mpl_::_1 {aka mpl_::arg<1>}'
error: template argument 3 is invalid
error: expected initializer before 'final_type'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `types<Ts...>` is a class and not a class template. However, your `add_to_types` expects a class template as the first argument. To get your `fold` expression to work, you could change `add_to_types` to take two class arguments and specialize `add_to_types` for the case of the first argument being `types<Ts...>`:

```
template <typename Seq, typename T>
struct add_to_types;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct add_to_types<types<Ts...>, T>
{
  typedef types<T, Ts...> type;
};
```